# Animated css gradient within element

Tags: css, wordpress, css-selectors, background-image, portfolio

I've got a portfolio WordPress theme I'm adapting, and can't figure out how to apply this gradient to a specific element of my front page. I've had a look around online and so far figured out that the code below needs a more accurate selector to apply to, but the issue is finding that for the element in question!

```
body
 {background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #47bcc2, #bee9e8, #c4e7d4, #00bd9d, #8bd7d2);
    background-size: 400% 400%;
 animation: gradient 15s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes gradient {
    0% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% 50%;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
}
```

So I'd like the animated gradient to sit inside the teal coloured background area (currently an image). When you scroll down the teal background and title text fade to white, revealing a grid of projects.

I don't want to apply the gradient to 'body', but I'm not sure where to apply it so it functions like the teal image - fading on scroll.

[This is the teal image element I'm trying to change in inspector - prior to any tweaks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMJRA.png)

I've managed to achieve the full body background with the image element disabled. It seems that the background-image overrides whatever gradient I try.

[Current view - applying gradient to body, with image element disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wI2Iq.png)

I *think* the trouble is down to the transition/fade element being coded into that image section and overriding the linear gradient - but I'm fairly new to these kinds of tweaks! Is anyone able to point me in the right direction please?

Thanks!

EDIT: Here's the original css for the hero-header I'm trying to adapt - is it a case of putting the gradient css somewhere in here?

```
.hero-header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 88; }
  .hero-header .media {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 88;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateZ(0) scale(1.015);
    transition: opacity 555ms cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1) 100ms, transform 555ms cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1) 200ms; }
    .hero-header .media.active {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: translateZ(0) scale(1); }
    .hero-header .media.unmount-transition {
      transition: opacity 400ms cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1);
      transform: translateZ(0) scale(1); }
```

Comment: As the image is a JPG, the image doesn't have transparency, hence, changing the background doesn't have any effect (I hope I understand your question), try png. But better, try splitting it into multiple images to allow a more responsive design.

Comment: The ``<span>`` with an image is in front of any body background there. You could find the header and try to remove that image. In the last case (not ideal), use ``.anyClassAsParent span { display: none! Important }``. Also, I'm not sure if you trying to add background to the whole body or only the header section.

Comment: Thanks for your replies! murb - I have tried with a png and it still doesn't work. I want to replace the image with the animated gradient if possible.

Comment: Azametzin - am trying to have the gradient background on the header section only. I guess I'm trying to override that image with the gradient if that's possible?

Comment: Also @Azametzin I tried `.anyClassAsParent span { display: none! Important }` and it didn't do anything? But if it did make the image display none, I'd still have the problem of trying to get the gradient to fade on scroll.

Comment: Remember that ``.anyClassAsParent`` should be a class that is parent of that span (in order to not affect other spans).

Comment: @Azametzin - hurrah! I got it to work... so now I'd like to have the gradient fade when the user scrolls down (is this maybe javascript or something else I need to tweak?)

Comment: Yes, For this you need JavaScript to "listen" to scroll. For CSS, probably you will need to use ``opacity`` and ``transition`` properties or similar to create the effect. For JavaScript you will add or remove a class that applies the effect depending on the scroll height the user is (using ``element.addEventListener("scroll", some function)`` or ``element.onscroll = some function``). Have good studies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve the effect I desired, this is what I used!

Turns out I just needed to point the selector to the correct span, then !important the gradient properties. Not best practice I know, but just for this section is perfect!

```
.hero-header span {background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, #47bcc2, #bee9e8, #c4e7d4, #00bd9d, #8bd7d2)!important;
    background-size: 400% 400%!important;
 animation: gradient 15s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes gradient {
    0% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% 50%;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
}
```